# Mongo DB: Splitting Chunk with Minimum/Maximum Hashed Key as Lower/Upper Bound

Tags: mongodb

This might be a silly question with obvious answer, but how do I split a chunk with minimum/maximum hashed key as lower/upper bound?

For example I have this chunk that I want to split:

```
{
    "_id" : "database-name.collectionName-_id_5232174760913548110",
    "lastmod" : Timestamp(5, 1),
    "lastmodEpoch" : ObjectId("5474796988a23861ead5dc60"),
    "ns" : "database-name.collectionName",
    "min" : {
        "_id" : NumberLong("5232174760913548110")
    },
    "max" : {
        "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }
    },
    "shard" : "dimA"
}
```

I tried splitting it with:

```
db.adminCommand( {
    split: "database-name.collectionName",
    bounds: [{_id: NumberLong("5232174760913548110")}, {{_id: {"$maxKey" : 1}}}] } )
```

, but failed with error message "no chunk found from the given upper and lower bounds".

The command works for chunks that are not at max/min key, so I think I'm not supposed to use  `{_id: {"$maxKey" : 1}}` as the upper bound.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Nina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just about how `$maxKey` is displayed versus how you pass it into the shell to use it in a command.  Easiest thing to do is show a working example, so here's my original layout of my test collection (`foo.bar`):

```
foo.bar
        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
        chunks:
            shard0000   3
        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("-4097713469691957209") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 3) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong("-4097713469691957209") } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("1468066378930898747") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 4) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong("1468066378930898747") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 2)
```

To split on that last chunk just do this:

```
db.adminCommand( {
    split: "foo.bar",
    bounds: [{_id: NumberLong("1468066378930898747")}, {_id: MaxKey}] } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Now, to prove it happened the layout looks like this:

```
foo.bar
        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
        chunks:
            shard0000   4
        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("-4097713469691957209") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 3) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong("-4097713469691957209") } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("1468066378930898747") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 4) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong("1468066378930898747") } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("5350365356528563634") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 5) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong("5350365356528563634") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 6)
```