# Mongodb sharding: Chunk split failed with Hashed Shard Key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to split few jumbo chunks in mongodb sharded cluster sharded using hashed shard key: {group_id:"hashed"}.

I used the following command from mongodb docs to split these jumbo chunks:

```
db.runCommand( { split: "test.people",
                  bounds : [ { group_id: NumberLong("-5838464104018346494") },
                             { group_id: NumberLong("-5557153028469814163") }
             ] } )
```

But getting following error:

```
{ "cause" : { }, "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "split failed" }.
```

What is the possible cause of this failure? The shard key group_id has cardinality 26231 against total 4521157 documents.

Have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172951/mongo-db-splitting-chunk-with-minimum-maximum-hashed-key-as-lower-upper-bound/27174899#27174899) disussion but unable to find the cause.

P.S : The group_id is ObjectId.

Comment: Have you tried using `middle` instead of `bounds`?

Comment: Yes..that is not working. As there is no query document I can specify for hashed key

Comment: Have you tried examining the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Your cardinality is **way** too small. One chunk will split automatically when he reaches 64mb.

Currently, with a cardinality of 26231, your collection can't be bigger than 26231*64mb maximum without jumbo chunks... And you will probably have problems a long time before that unless you have a perfect distribution.

In your case, you don't have any value of group_id resulting in a hashed value between NumberLong("-5838464104018346494") and NumberLong("-5557153028469814163")...

So you can't split it because your cardinality is too small.

To sum up, you need a better shard key **immediately** which means mongodump everything and then mongorestore with the new shard key.